# I am trying to create microservice based architecture using Django rest framework

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, cas

I have one DRF project called users where I will handle authentication and I have setup oauth2 and my API URL is

> http://localhost:8000/auth/login 
>   and this running fine

and I have one more DRF project called products and I have a URL

> http:localhost:8001/products/getProduct/1

but I am not able to get the solution on how to access the `user model` from

> users project

into

> products project

I am trying to implement the central authentication system(CAS) for my microservice-based project

Answer (score 3):

Trying to import users in your products project is against the principle of a microservice architecture.

You should handle authentication with an auth server where the user can log in and obtain something that identifies the user (typically a token).

And then the microservice (or some proxy/API gateway) has to validate this token againt the auth server

You can look at JWT for django rest framework for example to implement your solution.

Comment: thanks for response. i have also tried using drf jwt but not able to understand in product project how to get user permissions because of that i dint implement that.